# Gmail mail view doesn't recognise stylesheet but fine on Mailtrap

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, gmail

I am trying to send an email with the following HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Hello!</h1>
   <p class="content">
     <a href="https://laravel.com" style="color: #761c19;">Laravel</a>
   </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my controller code to send email:

```
$user = User::first();
    
Mail::send('emails.test_email', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->from('from@heavygari.com', 'HeavyGari');

        $m->to('to@gmail.com', 'Sohel Rana')->subject('Welcome to HeavyGari!');
});
```

Sending mail is working fine. But problem is about view. Email template shows as expected on **Mailtrap** with `css/stylesheet`. But when I check my email on **Gmail**, it is missing any kind of `css/stylesheet`.

### Edit

When I use markdown mailables, it is rendering css correctly.